# Unchaining grub2 and windows bootloader(s)

Tags: windows, ubuntu, bootloader, grub2

I would like to find out if it is possible to unchain grub2 and windows boot-loader and I could not find a convincing answer anywhere, perhaps it is just not possible...

The situation is as follows: The system has windows 7, windows 8 and Ubuntu installed. Grub2 loads first and sees (only) windows 8. If the windows 8 option is selected, windows boot loader takes over and gives the option to choose between windows 7 or Windows 8. This is a non-uefi system, where windows 7 was installed first and ubuntu last, and the partition table is:

sda1:system;sda2:windows 7; sda3:windows 8; sda4:(Extended); sda5:data; sda6:ubuntu; sda7:linux-swap

Question: Can I just lose windows boot-loader, that is, add windows 7 entry to grub2 and skip windows boot-loader all together? Or do I always need to "stop-over" two boot-loaders?

Thanks.

Edit:

No, I am not using EasyBCD and, no, I did not update grub after Ubuntu installation (the last:7,8,Ubuntu). My objective is to get rid of the second bootloader (not to get another one).  Though 7 bootloader does not see 8, I am still stuck with 8 bootloader giving me 7 also...

Edit2:

I was hopping the problem could be reduced to removing windows 7 entry from windows 8 bootloader (after updating grub with windows 7) but I could not update grub(?). I am starting to wonder if there are two windows bootloaders on sda1 or only one...

The problem will resolve itself as I am getting rid of windows 8 partition (again) and sticking with dual boot. I really don't know why I keep coming back. I guess I like the slick window style, if only we could have a kde plasma 5 style start menu, hide metro, hot corners...perhaps too much to ask. Anyway, I would still appreciate some insight on how to solve the problem at hand as I may want to try windows 10 (I am partial to odd editions but perhaps I feel bored one of these days).

Comment: Why isn't Windows 7 detected? What was the order of installation of the OSes? Do you have a 3rd party software like EasyBCD installed? Does `update-grub` work?

Comment: @RsyaStudios: He clearly says that he installed Win7 first and Ubuntu last, so Win7, Win8 and then Ubuntu. Grub should detect Win7 though.

Comment: Miner: It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  You should use the [contact form](http://superuser.com/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information these are http://superuser.com/users/453261/miner and http://superuser.com/users/454555/miner.  You’ll then be able to [edit], comment on and accept answers to this question.  … … … … … … …  But, if you believe that you have a solution to the problem, post it as an answer.